# Код не удаляет строку из файла, когда в файле одна строка

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит строку, которую хочет удалить из файла. Код перезаписывает в файл все строки кроме нужной. Когда остается одна строчка, она не удаляется. Нужно сделать так, чтобы удалялась последняя строка и файл становился чистым.

```
def zadachs():
    ask='Введите желаемый номер пункта (1 - просмотр текущих задач, 2 - запись новых задач, 3 - удаление существующей задачи, 4 - выход из программы): '
    vopros1='Напишите здесь Вашу новую задачу: '
    vopros2='Введите задачу, которую вы хотите удалить: '
    while True:
        b=input(ask)
        try:
            b=int(b)
        except ValueError:
            print("Введите номер пункта")
            continue
        if b==4:
            break
        if b==1:
            with open(r'C:\Users\username\test\zadachi.txt', 'r') as f:
                zd=f.read()
                print(zd)
                if len(zd)==0:
                    print("На текущий момент задач нет")
        elif b==2:
            zadacha = input (vopros1)
            with open(r'C:\Users\username\test\zadachi.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('\n' + zadacha)
        elif b==3:
            dell = input (vopros2)
            f=open(r'C:\Users\username\test\zadachi.txt', 'r')
            lines=f.readlines()
            f.close()
            f=open(r'C:\Users\username\test\zadachi.txt', 'w')
            f.truncate()
            for line in lines:
                if line != dell + '\n':
                    f.write(line)
            f.close()
        else:
            print('Такого пункта нет')
    
zadachs()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда у вас в файле остается одна строка, которую нужно удалить, ваш код ничего не записывает в файл, поэтому исходное его содержимое не удаляется (если записать что-то в файл открытый в режиме `'w'`, то файл будет очищен автоматически, но если ничего не записать, то очистка не произойдет). Можно принудительно очищать файл перед записью в него с помощью метода `truncate()`. Также, у последней строки в файле не будет символа `'\n'` в конце, поэтому нужно наоборот обрезать символ переноса строки (`.rstrip('\n')`) и сравнивать строки без него:

```
f=open(r'C:\Users\username\test\zadachi.txt', 'w')
f.truncate()  # Обрезать все содержимое файла, идущее после текущей позиции
for line in lines:
    if line.rstrip('\n') != dell:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: ошибку я исправил, но последняя остающаяся строка все равно не удаляется. Так же заметил что не могу удалить нижнюю строку в файле, только остальные.

Comment: добавил полностью код, подскажите пожалуйста, в чём заключается моя ошибка

Comment: @Nitrolacs дополнил ответ, попробуйте теперь

Comment: if line.rtrim('\n') != dell:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rtrim'

Comment: Поправил. rstrip должно быть. trim - это откуда-то из параллельной вселенной)

Comment: Все хорошо работает, но когда удаляю все строки, остаются пустые отступы в файле, вследствие чего не выводится строка "if len(zd)==0: ....".

Comment: Возможно у вас в файле есть строки состоящие только из пробелов. Проще всего сделать `zd=f.read().strip()`, тогда если строка состоит только из пробельных символов, она сократится до пустой строки.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь!